# Comparison of Non ASCII only works in IDLE

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, character-encoding

I'm doing a fairly simple code that transforms European Portuguese input into Brazilian Portuguese -- so there are a lot of accented characters such as á,é,À,ç, etc.

Basically, the goal is to find words in the text from a list and replace them with the BR words from a second list.

Here's the code:

```
#-*- coding: latin-1 -*-

listapt=["gestão","utilizador","telemóvel"]
listabr=["gerenciamento", "usuário", "celular"]

while True:

    #this is all because I need to be able to input multiple lines of text, seems to be working fine 

    print ("Insert text")
    lines = []

    while True:
        line = raw_input()
        if line != "FIM":
            lines.append(line)
        else:
            break
    text = '\n'.join(lines)    

    for word in listapt:
        if word in text:
            num = listapt.index(word)
            wordbr = listabr[num]
            print(word + " --> " + wordbr) #just to show what changes were made
            text = text.replace(word, wordbr)

    print(text)
```

I run the code on Windows using IDLE and by double-clicking on the `.py` file.
The code works fine when using IDLE, but does not match and replace characters when double-clicking the `.py` file.

Comment: Do you get the same error message if you add a basic `print "gestão"` somewhere?

Comment: No, I don't.  That seems to work fine.

Comment: I edited the question with a new problem -- it works through IDLE, but it doesn't when I run directly or convert to exe. Why?

Comment: What do you mean "convert to exe"?

Comment: I used py2exe to create an executable file, just to test it, as it's probably going to be the end goal of this.

Comment: Is this really your entire file verbatim? I suspect you've got some decode/encode hacks you've missed out.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack No, the lists of words are larger and there's some code after the translation for an optional export to a txt file. Nothing else.

But I created another one with just this section and the error is still there: runs well from IDLE, but simply doesn't translate if I double click.

Comment: Are you sure the error is exactly the same? The error given must be from the original code as there's a difference in spelling of `text` (=>`texto`). Can you re-run the code above and paste the traceback exception exactly?

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I'm sorry, the "texto" is just because I translated all the code to English for you gys, when I pasted here.

As I said in other comments, I no longer get the error I can run it perfectly in IDLE. Now it simply doesn't translate anything when run through cmd or double click. 

It turns out that specific error happened because I had a string `u"telemóvel"`from when I tried to solve the other problem (not translating or showing accents righ with double click or cmd).

I hope I'm not confusing you too much.
Bottom line now is: I can run it in IDLE, not cmd.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack should I post a new question and explain this more carefully?

Comment: It's ok - I'm writing an answer to let you know what to fix. I'll then fix the question to match :)

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Thank you! Please note that it translates everything fine, except all the words with accented characters (in cmd/double-click. In IDLE it translates everything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why the code works as expected in IDLE but not from CMD or by doubleclicking:

1. Your code is UTF-8 encoded, not latin-1 encoded
2. IDLE always works in UTF-8 "input/output" mode.
3. On Windows, CMD/Doubleclicking will use a non-UTF-8 8bit locale.
4. When your code compares the input to the hardcoded strings it's doing so at a byte level. On IDLE, it's comparing UTF-8 to hardcoded UTF-8. On CMD, it's comparing non-UTF-8 8bit to hardcoded UTF-8 (If you were on a stock MacOS, it would also work).

The way to fix this is to make sure you're comparing "apples with apples". You could do this by converting everything to the same encoding. E.g. Convert the input read to UTF-8 so it matches the hardcoded strings. The better solution is to convert all [byte] strings to Unicode strings (Strings with no encoding). If you were on Python 3, this would be all automatic.

On Python 2.x, you need to do three things:

1. Prefix all sourcecode strings with `u` to make them Unicode strings:

   ```
   listapt=[u"gestão",u"utilizador",u"telemóvel"]
   listabr=[u"gerenciamento",u"usuário", u"celula]
   ...
   if line != u"FIM":
   ```

   Alternatively, add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` to avoid changing all your code.
2. Use the correct coding header for the encoding of your file. I suspect your header should read `utf-8`. E.g.

   ```
   #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   ```
3. Convert the result of `raw_input` to Unicode. This must be done with the detected encoding of the standard input:

   ```
   import sys
   line = raw_input().decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
   ```

By the way, the better way to model list of words to replace it to use a dict. The keys are the original word, the value is the replacement. E.g.

```
words = { u"telemóvel": u"celula"}
```

Comment: OMG YES! It worked! Thank you!

Regarding your last note, that's a very good tip, thanks for that too!

Comment: Note that the Windows console is UTF-16, but by default Python 2 reads best-fit (non-strict) byte strings from the console. This uses the console's current input codepage, which defaults to the system locale's OEM codepage (e.g. 850 in Western Europe). You'll read mojibake nonsense for all characters that aren't defined in this codepage (e.g. "αβγδε" -> "aß?de"). The only reliable solution is to use the console's Unicode API (e.g. `ReadConsoleW`), as Python 3.6+ does. In Python 2 you can install and enable the win_unicode_console package.

Comment: There's no reason to mention CMD in this answer since the OP runs the script by double-clicking on the file. Bringing CMD into the discussion contributes to confusion that the console and CMD are the same thing. cmd.exe and python.exe are both console applications, which either inherit or allocate a console window that's implemented by the system (by conhost.exe in Windows 7+, but it's an implementation detail).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that problem over here.

Based on your use of raw_input, it seems like you're using Python 2.x

This may be because I'm copypasting off of stack overflow, and have a different dev environment to you.

Try running your script under the latest Python 3 interpreter, as well as removing the "#-*- coding:" line.

This should either hit UnicodeDecodeError issues a lot sooner in your code, or work fine.

The problem you have here is Python 2.x getting confused at some point while trying to translate between byte sequences (what Python 2.x strings contain, eg binary file contents), and human-meaningful text (unicode, eg for things like user informational display of chinese characters), because it makes incorrect assumptions about how human-readable text was encoded into the byte sequence seen in the Python strings.

It's a detail that Python 3 attempts to address a lot better/less ambiguously.

Comment: I tried that and I can actually run it in IDLE, but it doesn't work if I double click the file or open from the cmd.

The final goal of this is probably to create a sharable executable file, so running from IDLE isn't enough. Why is this happening?

Answer (score -1):

First try executing the code below, it should resolve the issue:

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

listapt=[u"gestão",u"utilizador",u"telemóvel"]
listabr=[u"gerenciamento",u"usuário", u"celular"]

lines=[]
line = raw_input()
line = line.decode('latin-1')
if line != "FIM":
    lines.append(line)

text = u'\n'.join(lines)    

for word in listapt:
    if word in text:
        print("Hello")
        num = listapt.index(word)
        print(num)
        wordbr = listabr[num]
        print(wordbr)
```

Comment: Do not hardcode `decode` - this assumes the terminal is using `latin-1`. This may work for the OP when they're double clicking or running from CMD. It won't work from IDLE.